# Matrix Becomes a vector space

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

Explain how addition and multiplication by scalar can be defined in a natural way for an $M_{m,n}$. So $M_{m,n}$ becomes a vector space.

#### Progress

I created two $m\times  n$ matrices and showed then when added they create an $m\times  n$  matrix. So, closed under addition. For the scalar multiplication, created an $C$ belonging to $F$ so $C$ times one of my $m\times  n$ matrices is $CF$.

Comment: You already have a (very natural) addition and a multiplication by a scalar for matrices. Why not checking whether it makes $M_{m,n}$ a vector space or not?

Comment: @azarel created two  m by n matrices and showed then when added they create an m by n matrix so closed under addition. For the scalar multiplication, created an C belonging to F so C times one of my m by n matrices is CF.

Comment: @Taladris because the question is only looking for addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: Have you tried figuring out what the dimension of that space would be? Shouldn't be too hard from there on.
Also, you just rephrased what @Taladris said

Comment: @JoBe: seems unnecessary just to show that $F^{m\times n}$ is a vector space, but a good exercise nonetheless.

Comment: But i could use the 4 axioms to show addition.

Comment: @par: But isn't this basically the solution to the problem? Creating an isomorphism from $M_{m,n}$ to $F^{mn}$ seems like the natural way to see it

Comment: What is an isomorphism? @JoBe

Comment: Sorry, I meant computing the dimension of $F^{m\times n}$ is unnecessary. Got distracted while typing.

Comment: Bob, that shouldn't be of too much interest to you now. @par says, computing the dimension of the vector space YOU are looking for is unnecessary. But now I'm asking you again: Do you know how many degrees of freedom you have for an $m\times n$-matrix? 

And as Taladris pointed out, addition of matrices and multiplication of matrices by scalars is well-defined. From these definitions, you should be able to see the vector space structure.

Comment: Sorry @JoBe i am not given any dimensions until the next question?

Comment: @BOB:forget about dimensions and isomorphisms for now. You will see these notions soon and you'll understand they can be used to solve easily this problem. From what you seem to know about vector spaces, the simplest is two defined the addition and the scalar multiplication as you did in your edited post. And then, check that all axioms for vector spaces are satisfied. It is not very informative if we do this task for you, so you should give it a try on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have matrices $A=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}\end{pmatrix},~ B=\begin{pmatrix}b_{11}&b_{12}\\b_{21}&b_{22}\end{pmatrix}$.

What does $A+B$ look like? And if $c$ is some scalar, what does $c\cdot A$ look like?

Compare your results to the axioms that need to be satisfied for a vector space.

---

EDIT: Okay, on dimension. If you have found the vector space structure, you will see that $2\times 2$-matrices , as I used to illustrate the problem, form a $4$-dimensional vector space with basis

$\{\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\}$

Comment: What I have done is checked is existence of zero vector, commutativity of addition,associativity of addition and existence of an inverse.

Comment: Using the standard operations on matrices, I assume. Hence you have shown that these are sufficient for the set of $m\times n$ matrices to be a vector space

Comment: Since the multiplication of matrices isn't used, just put all the rows the one after the other in one unique row and you get the classic standard vector space.